# Recover a deleted .gs file?

Tags: google-apps-script

I deleted one of my *.gs script files and I'm hoping there's a way to recover it.  I know that you can look at revisions of an existing file but is there a way to recover a deleted script (.gs) file?

Where are these files stored?

I checked google drive trash and it's not there.

Thanks,
Dave

Answer (score 1):

From this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44842952/recover-accidentally-deleted-google-apps-script-project), I think there is no way to recover except if you have a paid google account.

Unfortunately, it is not also available in the trash can of google drive.